# Where is vmlinux on my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I'm trying to work with starting up [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/docs/), and I'm running into a problem at this step:

```
opcontrol --vmlinux=/path/to/vmlinux
```

Ubuntu has no package called vmlinux, and when I do a `locate vmlinux`, I get a lot of files:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/h8300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-std.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-sun3.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/mn10300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/sh/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_32.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-14/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/h8300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-std.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-sun3.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/mn10300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/sh/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_32.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/h8300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-std.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/m68k/kernel/vmlinux-sun3.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/mn10300/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/sh/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_32.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux_64.lds
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-16/include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h
```

Which one of these is the one I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in your `/boot` directory - mu Ubuntu actually has compressed versions along the lines of `vmlinuz-2.6.28-16-generic`.

Whether oprofile can work with those is not a question I can answer.

Comment: What's with the edit? http://superuser.com/posts/62576/revisions

Comment: oprofile can't work with `vmlinuz` it requires uncompressed kernel.

Comment: vmlinux is not the same as vmlinuz

Answer (score 29):

The easiest(and non-hacky) way to obtain `vmlinux` under Ubuntu is to [add ddebs repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash):

```
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 428D7C01
```

and install kernel debug symbols:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

`vmlinux` then can be found here:

```
/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

Hm, just wanted to put this as a comment to the above answer by @paxdiablo, but cannot find the comment button? Anyways..

The thing is that the `vmlinuz` file is compressed - and for debugging purposes, you need an uncompressed `vmlinux` one (and preferably one built with debugging symbols - which the default `vmlinuz`-es coming with Ubuntu do not have, as they are stripped of symbols).

Now, it is possible to unpack a `vmlinuz` into a `vmlinux` file - however, that is not trivial; first you have to find a byte offset in `vmlinuz` where the compressed file starts, and then use `dd` and `zcat` to unpack only the necessary part. In detail, this is explained in: "[[ubuntu] How to trace this bug? - Ubuntu Forums - post #4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8062401&postcount=4)"; in brief, below is my example terminal command log, based on that post:

```
$ od -A d -t x1 /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) | grep '1f 8b 08 00' --colour
0013920 f3 a5 fc 5e 8d 83 70 23 3d 00 ff e0 *1f 8b 08 00*

$ wcalc 13920+12
 = 13932

$ dd if=/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) bs=1 skip=13932 | zcat > vmlinux-$(uname -r)
4022132+0 records in
4022132+0 records out
4022132 bytes (4,0 MB) copied, 42,1695 s, 95,4 kB/s

gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored


$ file vmlinux-2.6.32-25-generic 
vmlinux-2.6.32-25-generic: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

Well, hope this helps,

Cheers!

Comment: There is special script in kernel's git for that `extract-vmlinux`: https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=scripts/extract-vmlinux;hb=HEAD

Comment: Many thanks, @SaveTheRbtz - had no idea abut that.. Cheers!

Comment: This should be marked as default answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can download source and compile your own using the following command:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-2.6.32/
fakeroot make -f debian/rules binary-generic skipdbg=false
```

or you can download the ddeb package [here](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) and install it by `sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-60-virtual-dbgsym_3.2.0-60.91_amd64.ddeb`

Answer (score 2):

This is an an old question, and old answers don't work for me anymore (ubuntu 14.04).

1. First of all, **`vmlinux` is optional for `oprofile`**, you only need it to show what's happening inside the kernel, user-space profiling can be done without it. [Read more in the doc](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/faq/).
2. If you still need `vmlinux`, **add the ddebs repository** (shamelessly taken [from ubuntu's wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap)):

   ```
   codename=$(lsb_release -c | awk  '{print $2}')
   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename} main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
   EOF
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
   ```
3. Then **install debug symbols for your kernel**. You must do this each time you upgrade your kernel, after rebooting so that `uname` gets the right kernel version. Feel free to remove packages associated with old kernels.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
   ```
4. Once this package is installed, **you'll find the `vmlinux` file here**:

   ```
   /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-$(uname -r)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/289087

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial on packagecloud:blog](https://blog.packagecloud.io/how-to-extract-and-disassmble-a-linux-kernel-image-vmlinuz/) is very helpful.

Here's the gist of it:

1. Download Linus Torvalds' extract-vmlinux script.

   `wget -O extract-vmlinux https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux`
2. Install Linux headers.

   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
3. Copy the kernel image to a temporary directory.

   `mkdir /tmp/kernel-extract`

   `sudo cp /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) /tmp/kernel-extract/`
4. Run the `extract-vmlinux` script to extract the image.

   `cd /tmp/kernel-extract/`

   `sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/extract-vmlinux vmlinuz-$(uname -r) > vmlinux`

Answer (score 0):

Packages that contain linux kernel (the vmlinuz file) are called linux-image-VERSION-ARCH in Debian/Ubuntu.

You can list them with command `dpkg -l linux-image-*`, and for installed package (it has `ii` mark in first column) you can get a list of files in it with `dpkg -L linux-image-VERSION-ARCH`, e.g. `dpkg -L linux-image-2.6.31-17-386` for a recent Karmic install.

Notice that `l` is lowercase in first command and uppercase in second.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
apt-get linux-image.*-dbg
```

usually the vmlinux locates in /usr/lib/debug/ after installation

Answer (score 0):

vmlinux file is part of what's called Debug Symbol Packages.
Here's a good reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

First run this:

```
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
```

Then import keys by this:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

or this(eariler versions):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2EDC64DC5AEE1F6B9C621F0C8CAB6595FDFF622
```

then update package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

finally install debug package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

Another thing that's worth mentioning is that this doesn't work on WSL2's ubuntu. You have to manully build the vmlinux file yourself on WSL. On how to do it, check: https://microhobby.com.br/blog/2019/09/21/compiling-your-own-linux-kernel-for-windows-wsl2/

Answer (score -1):

it should be in your root ( / ). In ubuntu 8.10 it is a link pointing to /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-16-generic

do an

```
ls / -l | grep '^l'
```

you should find it

PS: not sure of the exact path name.